# Error in MySQL/SQL/PHP syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, mysqli

`ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1`

I get the above error thrown at me upon form submission.

The Form (HTML):

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="25" class="txtbx" placeholder="Username"><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="40" class="txtbx" placeholder="Password"><br>
   <input type="password" name="confirm_password" maxlength="40" class="txtbx" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br>
   <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" class="txtbx" placeholder="Email"><br>
   <input type="text" name="confirm_email" maxlength="50" class="txtbx" placeholder="Confirm Email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

The PHP:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("[host (snip)]", "[username (snip)]", "[password (snip)", "[database name (snip)]");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "<script>alert('Error connecting to MySQL:' . mysqli_connect_error())</script>";
}
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
$password2=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['confirm_password']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
$email2=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['confirm_email']);
if($password!=$password2)
{
  echo "<script>alert('The password and the password confirmation do not match.');</script>";
}
if($email!=$email2)
{
  echo "<script>alert('The email and the email confirmation do not match.');</script>";
}
if($username && $password == $password2 && $email == $email2)
{
  $addto=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
  VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");
  if (!mysqli_query($connect,$addto))
  {
    die('ERROR: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Successful!";
  }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

I don't understand this error.  Line one of the PHP code has no character '1'.  Is it supposed to be `mysql` instead of `mysqli`?

Thanks,
~Hom

Comment: This line doesn't make sense `if($username && $password == $password2 && $email == $email2)`

Comment: Plus, you're using `mysqli_query` twice. Change `if (!mysqli_query($connect,$addto))` to `if(!$addto)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the line you say doesn't make sense is probably supposed to be written like so: 
`if( $username && ($password == $password2) && ($email == $email2))`, where $username is being checked for a zero/nonzero value

Comment: How can `$username && $password == $password2` both equal `$password2`?

Comment: @RyanJ I figured as much, which is why I'm only putting in comments, and not an actual "answer". ;-)

Comment: They dont. `$username && $password == $password2` compares if `$username` is true and if `$password == $password2` is true.

Comment: @Mic1780 That's believable. However, [`this comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847099/error-in-mysql-sql-php-syntax#comment38581338_24847099) does hold water.

Comment: @Mic1780 $username is a string, treating it as a boolean makes no sense

Comment: The error is not referring to your PHP line number, it's the SQL command line number. You have a '1' somewhere in your SQL command that is in the wrong place.

Comment: @RyanJ The `1` I suspect is coming from the use of the first `mysqli_query` being called as true. OP is using it twice where it should not.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Can't believe I forgot those parenthesis....  Will keep that thing about the double-msqli queries in mind next time.

Comment: @Dagon `$username` will actually never be a string according to the documentation on mysqli_query. It will be one of the following: true booleon, false booleon, or mysqli_result object. In this case, it was type cast to a string of "1" because (bool)true==(int)1 and (int)1=='1' thus giving us a query string of '1'. EDIT: I'm dumb. $username is a string XD. i was thinking about $addto. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to change the code `if (!mysqli_query($connect,$addto))` to `if ($addto === false)`. This is because `$addto` can be of mixed values so by using === you look for the boolean `false` without type conversion. It will fix your problem.

For documentation of what mysqli_query can return, [click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and scroll down to return values.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of " and ':

```
echo "<script>alert('Error connecting to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."')</script>";
```

Enjoy your code.

Comment: You are definitely correct about misuse of quotes, but that is not what the OP is looking to resolve. Not trying to be rule but for future reference put something like this as a comment. =) Good catch though.